# SQL Server 2008 and Almost-Progressive Sum and Average?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, average

I have a table with several million rows, with an ID column and a DateTimeOffset column. The table simply tracks elapsed time for some operations.

Without touching a cursor or doing RBAR, how can I get the difference between each row, and then the average time among all rows?

For example, if row 1 is 12:00 and row 2 is 12:01 and row 3 is 12:03 then my result set would have row 1 with 0, row 2 with 1, and row 3 with 2. Then my next result set would have a value of 1.5.

Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this by joining on row numbers, something like:

```
WITH datanumbered AS (
   SELECT dateValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateValue) AS rownum
)
SELECT first.rownum, DATEDIFF(second, first.dateValue, second.dateValue) AS TimeDiff
FROM datenumbered first
    JOIN datenumbered second ON first.rownum = second.rownum - 1
```

Then the calculate average by using the above query as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each row has an identity value?
Have a forign key relationship on the table back to itsself.

As you insert each row you give it Fk of the previous row.

Then you can join the table back to itsself e.g.

```
Select row2.Offset - row1.Offset from Offsets row1 inner join Offsets row2 
on row1.IdentityCol = row2.ForignKeyCol
```

the last row is

```
Select avg(row2.Offset - row1.Offset) from Offsets row1 inner join Offsets row2 
on row1.IdentityCol = row2.ForignKeyCol
```

Hope this makes sense and is of use to you
BW

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each identity value is just 1 greater than the previous, you can do something using a subquery like so:

```
select testdate, DATEDIFF(SECOND, TestDate, 
     (select TestDate from TestDates tdIn where tdIn.TestId = tdOut.TestId + 1))
from TestDates tdOut
```